# Ajax request dont work on safari but work perfectly on chrome/firefox?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is my ajax , it work perfectly on chrome and firefox but not on safari , i dont know what is the problem here ? The js are loaded well but nothing happens in console

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     //NEW
     function checkMsg() {
         setTimeout(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/checkmsg.php?msg=1&rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
                 type: "GET",
                 success: function (data) {
                     console.log(data);
                     if (data && data != 0) {
                         $('#redheadmsg').show();
                         $('#redheadmsg').html(data);
                     }
                     if (data == 0) {
                         $('#redheadmsg').hide();
                     }
                 }
             });

             checkMsg();
         }, 5000);
     }

     checkMsg();
 });
```

Comment: What error do you get in Safari? Please add it to your question..

Comment: where can i see the error ? i get nothing in console

Comment: You should first check to see if the request is sent and received.  If it is, the error can be caught using the `error` callback in a similar fashion the success is run

Comment: the thing is console.log not working on my safari ??

Comment: As @SvenWritesCode suggested please add `error: function(e) {console.log(e);}` to the object passed to `$.ajax`. Let us know what you get